# Display a Modal Video in Blazor

Tags: javascript, blazor

I am trying to create a modal window for viewing videos in Blazor using this template -  https://codepen.io/JacobLett/pen/xqpEYE

I have put the function in jsfunctions.js file and I have a reference to it  - `<script src="jsfunctions.js"></script>` inside the Head tag in index.html

```js
function ModalShow() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // Gets the video src from the data-src on each button
    var $videoSrc;
    $('.video-btn').click(function() {
      $videoSrc = $(this).data("src");
    });
    console.log($videoSrc);

    // when the modal is opened autoplay it  
    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
      // set the video src to autoplay and not to show related video. Youtube related video is like a box of chocolates... you never know what you're gonna get
      $("#video").attr('src', $videoSrc + "?autoplay=1&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;showinfo=0");
    })

    // stop playing the youtube video when I close the modal
    $('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function(e) {
      // a poor man's stop video
      $("#video").attr('src', $videoSrc);
    })

    // document ready
  });
}
```

However, I do not know how to initialize the javascript function. 
I have tried using the following method inside the blazor component

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
  await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("ModalShow").AsTask();
}
```

However, I get this error:

```
Unhandled exception rendering component: $ is not defined
    ReferenceError: $ is not defined
        at ModalShow (https://localhost:5001/jsfunctions.js:10:5
```

I am new to Blazor and I have no knowledge of JavaScript. Is there a pure Blazor way of displaying a modal video?

Thank you.

Later edit:
The HTML code for the buttons:

```html
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary video-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Jfrjeg26Cwk" data-target="#myModal">
  Play Video 1 - autoplay
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <!-- 16:9 aspect ratio -->
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
          <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="" id="video" allowscriptaccess="always" allow="autoplay"></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```css
body {
  margin: 2rem;
}

.modal-dialog {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 30px auto;
}

.modal-body {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: -30px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like that:

```js
window.modalVideo = {
   init: () => {
        // Gets the video src from the data-src on each button
        var $videoSrc;
        $('.video-btn').click(function() {
          $videoSrc = $(this).data("src");
        });
        console.log($videoSrc);

        // when the modal is opened autoplay it  
        $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
          // set the video src to autoplay and not to show related video. Youtube related video is like a box of chocolates... you never know what you're gonna get
          $("#video").attr('src', $videoSrc + "?autoplay=1&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;showinfo=0");
        });

        // stop playing the youtube video when I close the modal
        $('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function(e) {
          // a poor man's stop video
          $("#video").attr('src', $videoSrc);
        });
   }
};
```

and

```cs
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
  if (firstRender)
  {
    await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("modalVideo.init");
  }
}
```

You also need to load JQuery in your intdex.html : `$` is JQuery

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Bootstrap js to open a bootstrap modal

```html
<script src="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

And Popper, because [bootstrap js depends on Popper.js](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/javascript/#dependencies)

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the input. After I have loaded JQuery, I no longer get `$ is not defined` but now I get no feedback on clicking any of the buttons that were supposed to show the modal videos. I have put a `https:` in the JQuery reference, thinking that this was the root of the problem.

Comment: It's in the link posted at the beginning of the question (https://codepen.io/JacobLett/pen/xqpEYE). I am updating the question to include the html and css code inline with the question

Comment: Thanks! I am certainly making progress because now the modals are shown. However, the video source is not loading, it is a blank modal. The js code in the link I have provided works and sets the `var $videoSrc;` each time the button is pressed. In my test project, the js is not triggered on button click and the variable is not set. Could it be because of the changes you made to the JS code? I am sorry to keep bothering you but I have no knowledge of JS and I cannot seem to create video modals without JS in Blazor.

Comment: No, it's probably because we must call the init scrypt on `OnAfterRenderAsync` only on 1st render. I updated the answer

Comment: That was it. As a side note, updating your question step by step helped me more because otherwise I would not have analyzed each piece of info and I would have taken it for granted. :)